# Enterprise Architect and Multiple Projects

Tags: svn, enterprise-architect

I'm working with EA and SVN. Each member of the team have a eap at your machine.
I want to configure some stuff on EA, like Auto Name and Encounters. How can I configure and save for all members of the SVN?
And this counter need to be synced by SVN. Because, when someone create a object, need to increase for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, but you can't. EA does not support this.

Certain settings can be shared between projects. These are either packaged as MDG Technologies, or exported/imported as Reference Data. However, auto name counters cannot be shared in either way - reason being that they keep changing (the counter gets updated every time an element is created) and so you'd have to export, distribute and reimport the counters in every other project every time someone created an element.

Sharing shared settings is not supported by version control. In other words, EA has no concept of versions of these settings. (There is a version identity associated with an MDG Technology, but it's only a label.) So even if you were to export Reference Data from one project and store it in Subversion, the other modellers' EA installations would not think to go look in Subversion for updated Reference Data to import.

EA uses Subversion as a package repository only. Each modeller's project is separate, and the settings are individual - in fact, different modellers are not just free to change their project settings individually, but they can also select which version-controlled packages they include in their project.

The situation you are describing is one where you want the project itself (with all its settings) to be shared, not just the packages. This can be achieved in two ways: a shared .EAP file (works for a small team), or a database repository (by far the best solution). With this deployment model, I always recommend disabling (Subversion) version control of packages in favour of User Security / Locks, and Baselines.

There is one more deployment model supported by EA, and it might be indicated here (but I don't think so): replication. With this model, one project is the Master and the others are Replicas, and you can synchronize all changes from a Replica back into the Master.

This still is not the same as having a single project, however, and your different modellers creating new elements in different replicas will give rise to naming conflicts when you synch the replicas back.

So if you need the auto name counters to be shared between modellers, the only way is to set up a single project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [DBMS](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/projects_and_teams/createopenmodelfileoverview.html)  with Enterprise Architect. I use this option since about one year. Within this DBMS / database there are several projects. And each project can have reference Data and certain tagged values / stereotypes and so on. And this values and settings you can e.g. set under appearance certain colors, fonts, names etc.

But what do you exactly mean with Auto Name and Encounters? 
Please provide a link with this information.